# Excel VBA loop folder and check if Excel file name is equal to worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in need of some enlightment.
I'm trying to match a folder of Excel files with some sheets in an Excel workbook. So far, I'm able to read these Excel files names and corresponding sheets and copy to them to `sheet1` `B1` of my workbook. After that I create a sheet for every file.

I would like the macro to continue and compare every file in the directory with the sheets I have in my workbook. If the sheet name from workbook is equal to filename, than copy file contents (only `sheet1` from these files has data).

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub readme()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "D:\Claro Chile\Report_sem_formulas\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

        Do While fileName <> ""

             i = i + 1
             j = 2
             Cells(i, 1) = fileName
             Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

                    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets

                    Workbooks("Report Status v1.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value = sheet.Name

                    j = j + 1

        Next sheet

    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call create_sheets_starting_from_B1

End Sub

Sub create_sheets_starting_from_B1()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("B1")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell

Sheets("Summary").Move Before:=Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thks Peh, Will improve for next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

untested!

but do you might need something like:

```
Sub sheetCompare()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mDirs As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim OutFile As Variant, SrcFile As Variant
    Dim file As Variant

    OutFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    mDirs = "c:\" 'your dir here
    file = Dir(mDirs)
    While (file <> "")
        path = mDirs + file
        Workbooks.Open (path)
        SrcFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        For i = 1 To Workbooks(OutFile).Sheets.Count
            If file = Workbooks(OutFile).Sheets(i).Name Then
                'copy logic
            End If
        Next i
        Workbooks(file).Close (False)
        file = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm getting an ever ending loop :D .

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I forgot to step to the next file. see last two lines

Comment: Have no idea how to perform the copy logic... have it in my mind but cant seem to figure out how to do it

Comment: Record a macro, copy and paste something, modify code to account for sheet names and copy range.

Comment: Got it :    Code updated with copy logic.  @tretom Thks for the help !!